# Ho to get the cartesian product of element based a given criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a List of tuples in the form `[(a, 1), (b,1), (c,2),(d,2)]`. Im looking to generate a new list with the following elements: `[(a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d)]`.

What is the best way to do that in python

Comment: "based a given criteria" such as what?

Comment: what's the criteria for choosing elements in the new list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first = [x for (x,y) in data if y==1]
second = [x for (x,y) in data if y==2]

return itertools.product(first, second)
```

Comment: With this solution, both first a second can have duplicate element. As a result we will  have duplicate element in the product

Comment: @moudi Yes—surely the Cartesian product of [a, a] and [b] should be [(a,b), (a,b)]? If you don't want that, change all the square brackets in the code to curly braces, which will make it use sets instead of lists; sets ensure uniqueness.